# AngularJS unit-test outside the browser

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing

Dumb question of the day. Is there a way to unit-test legacy AngularJS code outside the browser in a nodeJS environment? I'm currently stubbing out the entire browser in a Jasmine helper.js file as I attempt to load the angular module. I know this is not going to work as I'm literally building a AngularJS for nodeJS mock framework. Does it even make sense to try this? I just wanna unit test my code without using Karma which loads a browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious to why you need to do this.  AngularJS is an in-browser framework so I would say no, but I've never heard of this problem or tried myself.

Comment: I want to run unit-tests on my CI server without having to futz with browsers, headless shenanigans etc. I also know that cutting the browser out will make the tests run faster.

Comment: Actually, I have an actual solution which is the same recipe I've used for years on Android... separating the business logic from the framework (Angular) code, but I'm looking for a cheaper incremental approach.

Comment: @Cliff Why not use phantomjs? But it's like a real browser only difference would be test cases will be executed on command line itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! There was a phantomjs folder sitting in our project for ever and I didn't even know what it was! LOL! It looks like the project has been suspended which is not good for long term.